# Integrate emoji in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, emoji

I'm building rails application, In my app peoples can write posts and reply to posts. As we know in a lot of applications that have posts, there is the ability to add emoji in the post.
I will be happy to get a source or tutorial how can I add emoji into my rails application.

Thanks very much!

Comment: gemoji gem provided by github

Comment: https://github.com/github/gemoji

Comment: Thanks, I saw this gem but I am very confused about it... it's not clear to me what I need to do..

Comment: A google search of "rails gemoji tutorial" returns this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/38ir3m/how_exactly_do_you_add_emoji_to_a_rails_app_and) from 2 years ago. Try google first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the gem: https://github.com/github/gemoji

More explanation about implementation:
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/38ir3m/how_exactly_do_you_add_emoji_to_a_rails_app_and/