# Rails: adding emojis in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want emojis in textfield. What should i do?

```
<%= f.text_field :message, class: 'form-control', data: { emojiable: true, autocomplete_source: @m_channel_users.order(:name).map { |t| 
            { :label => '@' + t.name} } }, id: 'tags' %>
```

Comment: There's another post that has this as an asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023850/integrate-emoji-in-rails-app#answer-51001713 not sure if thats what you're looking for but it might help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use emoji-picker library and inline script in your erb file.

```
<script>
      $(function() {

          window.emojiPicker = new EmojiPicker({
              emojiable_selector: '[data-emojiable=true]',
              assetsPath: 'http://onesignal.github.io/emoji-picker/lib/img/',
              popupButtonClasses: 'fa fa-smile-o'
          });

          window.emojiPicker.discover();
      });
</script>
```

Comment: It is not appear.What should i do?

Comment: have you included emojipicker library

Comment: I used emojipicker gem. Emoji icon is not appear in my textfields. What should i do?